# SQLite Result is out of order when using DISTINCT

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite query in which I am ordering the results by date.  This works fine.  However, when I introduce "DISTINCT" into the SQL statement, the results no longer stay in order.

Any thoughts?

```
SELECT date 
FROM details 
ORDER BY date(date); // Results are ordered correctly

     April 04, 2011
     April 04, 2011
     April 04, 2011
     April 03, 2011
     April 01, 2011
     March 25, 2011
```

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT date 
FROM details 
ORDER BY date(date); // Results are out of order

     April 01, 2011
     April 03, 2011
     April 04, 2011
     March 25, 2011
```

Comment: Can you post the actuall returned data for both queries?

Comment: can you post the results that you get

Comment: Updated my original post with the results.

Comment: I think the order by on the first query is returning in order coincidentally - try taking the order off and see what results you get: `SELECT date FROM details;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `date` column is not in recognized by the `date()` function, so `date(date)` gives `NULL`.

Try both queries with `ORDER BY NULL` you'll have the same results as with `ORDER BY date(date)`

Without `DISTINCT` it's ordering them by insert order.

With `DISTINCT`, the order comes from `DISTINCT`itself and is applied to the `date` column which is a text so it's in alphabetic order.

SQLite does not support *month names*. Change your data to supported formats (see [*Date And Time Functions*](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)) or transform the date column to recognized format before giving it to `date()`(with string functions)

For example (transforming `date` to the format `YYYY-mmm-dd` before calling `date()` works):

*(here `CASE WHEN` is limited to your data, you can extend it to all months)*

```
SELECT DISTINCT date 
  FROM (SELECT *,
               substr(date, -4) year,
               substr(date, -8, 2) day,
               trim(substr(date, 1, length(date)-8)) month
         FROM details) as details
 ORDER BY date(year
               || '-'
               || CASE WHEN month = 'April' THEN '04' ELSE '03' END
               || '-'
               || day)
```

, will give the correct results with or without `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Interesting. I will try to format my data into a supported format and then give it a go. I'll let you know what I find - thanks1

Comment: Did you try it? I'm curious as to whether it can work in SQLite, because I'm used to the restriction in SQL Server that prohibits you from ordering by any columns/expressions that are not in the select list when DISTINCT is applied.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, thank you! I appreciate the time you spent working that up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your date string is in a valid date format.

Try running this SQL to see what you get:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) FROM details;
```

If you get errors, it is not parsing your dates correctly.

Your second query is returning in alphabetic order, not chronological order - if it is not a valid date in that field, that would be the reason.

Comment: BrianH, I ran this query in SQLite Database Browser against my database, and it reports "No Error", however there are no results to show.  Is this correct?  The dates in the 'date' field are in the format: April 01, 2011.  Any thoughts?